# Summing multiple dynamically declared variables (fast)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing a program where I have multiple columns which I need to show the sum of to anEnd-user. These columns are assigned in the table ColumnTest in the column ColumnNames and their names can be changed by the user. Therefore I need to look up all the column names in ColumnTest\ColumnNames and afterwards sum all values regarding these columnnames from the outputtable.

I have previously used this script where I get all the columnnames in @cols like this [col1].[col2].[col3] and so on, but when I try to run the query I'm not able to sum these columns using '+ @cols + '. When I run this I get the following error: The SUM function requires 1 argument(s). Is there a viable option to do this procedure, without compromising the loading-time substantially?

```
DECLARE 
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.ColumnNames) 
            FROM ColumnTest c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

set @query = 
    '
    SELECT
        ID
        ,SUM('+ @cols + ')
    FROM Output_table
    GROUP BY
        ID
        '
execute(@query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
DECLARE 
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='',
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols += 'SUM('+ColumnNames+') as ['+ColumnNames+'],'
from
(
    SELECT distinct ColumnNames FROM ColumnTest
)A

SELECT @cols=LEFT(@cols,LEN(@cols)-1)

set @query = 
    '
    SELECT ID,'+ @cols + '
    FROM Output_table
    GROUP BY ID
    '
execute(@query);
```

or if you want addition of all column values you can use below query

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='',
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols += ''+ColumnNames+'+'
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ColumnNames FROM ColumnTest
)A

SELECT @cols=LEFT(@cols,LEN(@cols)-1)

set @query = 
    '
    SELECT ID,SUM('+ @cols + ')
    FROM Output_table
    GROUP BY ID
    '
execute(@query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use comma separated like ','
You can use '+'

Try this

```
DECLARE 
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct '+' + QUOTENAME(c.ColumnNames) 
            FROM ColumnTest c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

set @query = 
    '
    SELECT
        ID
        ,SUM('+ @cols + ')
    FROM Output_table
    GROUP BY
        ID
        '
execute(@query);
```